# Adicionar um blog a um site ja construido em WP

Tags: wordpress

Minha cliente ja tem um site do comercio dela ela quer mais um  canal, BLOG, pensei criar outra pasta blog e fazer uma nova instacao wp, pois la teria liberdade para temas, ou pensei criar uma nova categoria BLOG n instalacao WP que ja tenho, mas nao teria liberdade para estilizar, alguma ideia de como resolver isso da melhor forma?

Answer (score 1):

O site já existe em Wordpress?
Sendo assim não há necessidade de uma nova instalação, é possível apenas criar uma nova página site/blog e chamar as postagens. Porque não poderia estilizar? É claro que deve casar com o restante do site, mas pode estilizar o que quiser em uma só página através de css.
De qualquer forma não há problema também se preferir fazer uma nova instalação em subpasta. Só acho desnecessário uma nova configuração e espaço de hospedagem.

Não existe regra com relação a pasta ou subdominio blog.site 
Se preferir subdominio pode optar por uma nova instalação também ou usar a função multisite que possivelmente facilite sua vida, pois teria como acessar as mesmas configurações e ao mesmo tempo daria liberdade para usar tema independente e outras funções.

A nível de SEO seria ligeiramente melhor utilizar o blog em pasta ao invés de subdomínio pois facilita a lógica de linkjuice.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendaria você criar um **subdomínio** ao invés de uma **subpasta**, vai te dar menos dor de cabeça (permalinks, httacess...) e cria um senso de unidade p/ o blog.

Lá você faz a instalação da mesma forma que você fez para o domínio principal. Depois cria um link no menu do site principal para o sub.seusite.com.br.